# deleting some special words of a file and write unique words into a new file

Tags: python

I have 2 files, one is a text file containing some sentences. The other is a file which contains the words I want to delete them from the file. first I have to omit the special words, and then write the unique words into a new file, each word in a line. here is the code I wrote. but it doesn't work. in simple words I want to omit some words first then find unique words.

```
file1 = open('c:/python34/SimilarityCorpus.txt','r')
file2 = open('c:/python34/ListOfStopWords.txt','r')
file3 = open('c:/python34/Output1.txt','w') 

first_words=[]
second_words=[]
z=[]

for line in file1:  # to write unique words
   for word in line.split():
       if word not in z:
          z.append(word)
for line in file1:
 words = line.split()
  for w in words:
   first_words.append(w)

for line in file2:
  w = line.split()
   for i in w:
    second_words.append(i)

for word1 in first_words :
 for word2 in second_words:
   if word1==word2:
    first_words.remove(word2)

for word in first_words:
 file3.write(word)
 file3.write(' ')

file1.close()
file2.close()
file3.close()
```

I know that's basic, but I'm new in programming.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to programming! It's a fun world here :). I hope the answer below will help you.

Firstly, you are looking to get every unique word. Here, the `set` object may be useful for you. Using the `set`, you can iterate over every word and add it to the set, without worrying about duplicates.

```
z = set()
for line in file1:  # to write unique words
   for word in line.split():
       z.add(word)
```

From my understanding of your code, you want to find the difference between the `SimilarityCorpus` and the `ListOfStopWords`, and then write that to disk. Since you are only interested in unique words, and not worried about the counts, then `sets` can come to your rescue again.

```
first_words = set()
for line in file1:
    words = line.split()
    first_words = first_words.union(words)
```

Here, the `sets().union(other_iterable)` operation simplifies the need to iterate over the new words. You can do likewise for `second_words`.

Finally, you want to take the difference between two sets, which is also available in Python. To do that, you either will be looking for:

- words in `first_words` that are absent in `second_words`, or
- words in `second_words` that are absent in `first_words`.

In the first case, you would do:

```
first_words.difference(second_words)
```

In the second case, you would do:

```
second_words.difference(first_words)
```

More documentation on sets can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) on the Python docs. I would encourage you to use Python 3 rather than 2, which I see you are, so keep sticking with it!

To write to disk, with each word on a new line, you can do the following:

```
for word in first_words:
    file3.write(word)
    file3.write('\n')  # this will write a new line.
```

Currently, you have the following code pattern:

```
file3 = open('/path/to/your/file.txt', 'w')
# do stuff with file3, e.g. write.
file3.close()
```

I might suggest that you do, instead:

```
with open('/path/to/file3.txt', 'w') as file3:
    # do stuff with file3.
```

In this way, you don't need to explicitly open and close the file; the "with open" line can automatically take care of that for you.

I believe the rest of your code is correct, for reading and writing information from and to the disk.

If you could update your question to include more detail on errors that are cropping up, that would really help! Finally, whatever answer you find most useful here, don't forget to upvote/accept it (it doesn't have to be mine, I'm happy to simply add to the corpus of information and help around here).

Comment: thanks. please don't attention  to the names of the files. (similarityCorpus,...), this code is a part of an other bigger code that I have to write. here I just don't know how should I put unique words in to a file, after I omit the words of the second file from the first file. I mean where should write the z = set()
for line in file1:  
   for word in line.split():
       z.add(word)   exactly, and at the end how should I write them into a file? (I mean the last part of the code). how can I change this part:     for word in first_words:
 file3.write(word)
 file3.write(' ')

Comment: @sara: I have updated my answer to highlight how to write to a new line. You have done it correctly, but writing to a newline was omitted in your original code. I hope this helps!